# searching technique using node.js in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on a project in which the people search for the city and they get the results matching the city in the database. I am using node.js and MongoDB.i am not able to find the solution.

Comment: Need more detail. Tell us if you are looking for a query /  how to extract the same in frontend or anything else.

Comment: yes i am looking for the query which would check for the city entered in the search box and then search for the city in the database and display the results according to the city.